# Angular 5 disable header check with HttpClient / HttpHeader

Tags: web

I'm using Angular's HttpClient and HttpHeader to make a request to the api of a particular web game. The api does an origin check along with some other header based checks. When trying to set the Host, Referer, Accept-Encoding, User-Agent, Origin, and Connection headers Angular refuses with the message "Refused to set unsafe header '.'" Is there any way I can disable safe header checks similar to the method in AJAX?

Here is an example of disabling safe header checks in ajax:

`$.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(xmlHttpRequest) {
            // Requires node-XMLHttpRequest version 1.5.1 or later to set some headers in Node.js
            if(xmlHttpRequest.setDisableHeaderCheck) 
              xmlHttpRequest.setDisableHeaderCheck(true);
            return true;
        }
    })`

This is the header I'm trying to set:

`headers = headers.set('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8')
                     .set('Host', '<game-host>')
                     .set('Referer', '<game-domain>')
                     .set('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, sdch')
                     .set('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3 WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36')
                     .set('<game-name>-Session', 'ap_session=undefined')
                     .set('Origin', '<game-domain>')
                     .set('Connection', 'keep-alive')
                     .set('Accept', 'application/json, text/javascript, */* q=0.01')
                     .set('Content-Type', 'application/json charset=utf-8')
                     .set('<agent>', '1|Web-FB|Chrome 39.0.2171.65|0|Windows|0|1.1||en||1')
                     .set('<referer-string>', 'true');`

Comment: I'm facing this same problem. I just would like to add 'Accept-Encoding', 'application/gzip' in my headers.